# NET1.1 Conditional Compilation

Tags: c#, .net-1.1, conditional-compilation

I hope this is a very easy one to solve.

I have a crypto library that will be used for NET1.1 apps and higher. The X509Certificate class is in NET1.1 and X509Certificate2 is in NET2.0 and above.

I want to do something like:

```
#if NET1.1
public void LoadKeys(X509Certificate cert)
{
....
}
#else
public void LoadKeys(X509Certificate2 cert)
{
....
}
#endif
```

What I'm missing is the compiler symbol!

I found that NET20, NET30 and NET40 exist. However I want to do "if NET1.1, do this; otherwise, go with the advanced model".

Also, bonus question :), do I have to compile in NET1.1 and NET2.0 separately for this to work as intended?

Or can I compile the DLL in NET1.1 and then put in a machine with only NET2.0, and hopefully the ILM will go to the new framework?

Thanks

Comment: Please give more detail than "it doesn't work".

Comment: You have to compile in NET1.1 and NET2.0 versions an later up to a 4.0 version separately only if you are using an incompatible subsets of code features, including APIs, delegates, anonymous delegates, anonymous structures, tulips, generics, e.t.c (fond in .NET FW 4.0)

Comment: You can not compile source code with a new language features like anonymous structures on an old compiler

Comment: forget about my "yes, it doesn't work", not related at all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code already does what you want - if there's no "NET1.1" symbol defined, it will use the second piece of code.

And yes, you have to compile separately for 1.1 and 2.0 for this to work, because you'll end up with different results - one will end up with only the first overload; one will end up with only the second overload.

You probably *could* run the 1.1 code in 2.0 and higher - that's the normal case - but as you can't have a single build which contains both versions of the method *and* is 1.1-compatible, you might as well use two builds.

One option is for both methods to appear in the .NET 2+ build though, to retain backward compatibility for apps originally built against the 1.1 build which want to migrate:

```
public void LoadKeys(X509Certificate cert)
{
....
}
#if !NET1.1
public void LoadKeys(X509Certificate2 cert)
{
....
}
#endif
```

EDIT: Just to clarify a few points from the discussion with Artur in comments:

- Artur's blanket statement that you can't use a .NET 1.1 in a .NET 4 application is definitely wrong. I've just done so with the .NET 1.1 build of NUnit (which was the simplest .NET 1.1 library I had to hand)
- If you're relying on Code-Access Security then there *have* been changes there between framework versions; you'd have to look at the details of what you're doing to see whether the differences are significant
- You *can't* build a .NET 2 assembly and run it in .NET 1.1 due to binary format changes - it's only the other way round that works.
- While it's *possible* that you're relying on a call in .NET 1.1 which has been removed from a later version of .NET, that's a pretty rare case, and should be reasonably easy to determine. In general Microsoft tries to maintain backward compatibility pretty well.

You might also want to read the [.NET 4 Migration Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee941656.aspx).

Finally, I'd point out that .NET 1.1 is *really* old now - if you know you need to support it, then that's fair enough, but personally I'd try to get clients to upgrade if at all possible :)

Comment: it worked :) however, I would have to define a build for each fw and that needs time, which I don;t have as much as I would like.

Comment: @Kat: Do you really? What difference do you need between the other various framework versions? If there's more stuff you want to take advantage of, you would need to cover that with a separate build - but if you're happy with what's in .NET 2.0, then you don't need anything more than a 1.1 build and a 2.0 build.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: You are terribly wrong. While it is possible to use a code for 1.1 in 2.0 FW, .NET 1.1 is not binary compatible with .NET 4.0 just because there are differences in a file format, for example, natively generated assembly in .NET 4.0 contains some metadata info and cannot be stripped out, but for .NET 1.1 this is not true and the metadata info can be stripped out from a generated exe, which flaws a security for an assembly.

Comment: @Artur: It sounds like you're talking about *forward-compatibility*. I never claimed that would work - I was saying that the 1.1 assembly could be used in .NET 2 and higher.

Comment: thanks all for the answers. I'm using NET1.1 because I have a big app on that and the library I'm building needs to be for both this and other apps that are already in NET2 and above. And using NET1.1 DLL in NET2.0 apps does work (perhaps some things doesn't like CAS, but haven't find it so far).